# Need help "printing" array HORIZONTALLY - PHP from CSV file

Tags: php, csv

Why is the out output is in columns not rows. I basically want the rows to be alternating colors, which I found out is not working - seems to be columns.

```
<?php

$count = 0;

$input = 'https://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.csv';

echo "<html><body><table width=250>";

echo "<th bgcolor=#222937><FONT COLOR=WHITE SIZE=3>Bank Name</FONT></th>";
echo "<th bgcolor=#222937><FONT COLOR=WHITE SIZE=3>City</FONT></th>";
echo "<th bgcolor=#222937><FONT COLOR=WHITE SIZE=3>Acq. Institution</FONT></th>";
echo "<th bgcolor=#222937><FONT COLOR=WHITE SIZE=3>Closing Date</FONT></th>";


if (false !== ($ih = fopen($input, 'r'))) 
{
fgetcsv($ih);
    while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($ih))) 
    {    
        $outputData = array($data[0], $data[1], $data[4], $data[5]); 

        echo "<tr>";

            foreach ($outputData as $row)
            {               
                if($count % 2 == 0)
                    $rowColor = '#000000';
                else
                    $rowColor = '#222937';

                echo "<td bgcolor='. $rowColor . '><FONT COLOR=D3AB04 SIZE=2>" . htmlspecialchars($row) . "</FONT></td>";
                $count++;               

            }   

        echo "</tr>";

    }

    fclose($ih);
    echo "</table></body></html>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you have your words mixed up, sound like you want them *vertically* (up and down). Because the code you have does list them horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$input = 'https://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.csv';
echo "<html><body><table width='250' class='TFtable' >";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th bgcolor=#222937><FONT COLOR=WHITE SIZE=3>Bank Name</FONT></th>";
echo "<th bgcolor=#222937><FONT COLOR=WHITE SIZE=3>City</FONT></th>";
echo "<th bgcolor=#222937><FONT COLOR=WHITE SIZE=3>Acq. Institution</FONT></th>";
echo "<th bgcolor=#222937><FONT COLOR=WHITE SIZE=3>Closing Date</FONT></th>";
echo "</tr>";

if (false !== ($ih = fopen($input, 'r'))) 
{
fgetcsv($ih);
    while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($ih))) 
    {    
        $outputData = array($data[0], $data[1], $data[4], $data[5]); 

        echo "<tr>";

            foreach ($outputData as $row)
            {               
                echo "<td><FONT COLOR=D3AB04 SIZE=2>" . htmlspecialchars($row) . "</FONT></td>";
                $count++;               

            }   

        echo "</tr>";
    }

    fclose($ih);
    echo "</table></body></html>";
}

?>
```

and CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    .TFtable{
        width:100%; 
        border-collapse:collapse; 
    }
    .TFtable td{ 
        padding:7px; border:#4e95f4 1px solid;
    }
    /* provide some minimal visual accomodation for IE8 and below */
    .TFtable tr{
        background: #b8d1f3;
    }
    /*  Define the background color for all the ODD background rows  */
    .TFtable tr:nth-child(odd){ 
        background: #b8d1f3;
    }
    /*  Define the background color for all the EVEN background rows  */
    .TFtable tr:nth-child(even){
        background: #dae5f4;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining why this is working? What did you discover in OPs code that was causing problems? Not just for OP, but for others that might run into the same issue in the future and find your answer here.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are using the CSS file to highlight/offset the rows, correct? The css file is on the server is called additionl.css how do I point the code to the css names so that it works correctly? Thanks.

Comment: I mean, let's for the sake of arguement assume that you don't know how to calculate `1+1`. Someone tells you the answer is 2. Great! But what will you do the next time someone asks you what `2+3` is? Give a man a fish, and he'll eat for a day. Teach him how to fish, and he'll eat for a lifetime. That's why I'm asking you :)

Comment: @Kirk He's using classes for css. So you simply add `<table class='TFtable'>` to your code.